# Limit 1 data jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Если я использую запрос по типу

```
@Query("... LIMIT 1")
```

Нужно ли мне помещать ответ в List или в Optional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.. LIMIT 1` может использоваться только в нативных запросах (для которых параметр `nativeQuery = true`).

Если нужно ограничить количество строк в возвращаемом результате, этого можно добиться разными способами, см. документацию [JPA :: Defining Query Methods :: Limiting Query Results](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/repositories/query-methods-details.html#repositories.limit-query-result)

- При помощи разбития на страницы, передавая параметр `Pageable`, т.е. вызывая метод с параметром `PageRequest.of(0, 1)`:

```java
List<User> findByName(String name, Pageable pageable);
```

- При помощи параметра `Limit`:

```java
List<User> findByLastname(Limit limit);
```

- Используя ключевые слова `First` / `Top` (без дополнительного численного аргумента, чтобы возвращать единственный результат), но с этими ключевыми словами нельзя будет использовать параметр `Limit`:

```java
User findFirstByOrderByLastnameAsc();

User findTopByOrderByAgeDesc();
```

Также для запросов, для которых размер результата ограничен и не превышает 1, результат может оборачиваться в `Optional`:

```java
Optional<User> findFirstByFirstnameOrderByLastnameAsc(String firstname);
```